# mysqldump: specify per-user db name in ~/.my.cnf

Tags: mysql, arch-linux, mysqldump, mariadb

I'm running a shared server with multiple users. Each user has their own database in MySQL and associated credentials. I've created a template systemd timer & service (ie. *sitetasks@.timer* & *sitetasks@.service*) to run *mysqldump* daily to backup each users database. User-specific information is read by *mysqldump* from the *.my.cnf* file in each users' home directory.

I can then run the systemd timer/service for a specific user (ie. *sitetasks@user1.service*) to have that user's database backed up.

However, I can't find a way to specify the database name in *.my.cnf*.  I've looked at the *--databases* option but this is just a flag, not a way to specify a database or set of databases.

I can think of several ways to solve this differently:

1. create user-specific systemd timer/service -- but this doesn't scale well
2. drop a .db-name file into the users home directory and read it when calling mysqldump (something like mysqldump $(cat .db-name) > backup.sql) - but now I need an additional file
3. similar to #2 but parsing each user's *wp-config.php* (the db's are for Wordpress)
4. ensure the db-name is always the same as the user name

None of these are as scalable & portable as being able to use MySQL's existing *.my.cnf* options file though.

Is there a way to specify a default database name in *.my.cnf*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every user has access to the database to which he was given access rights, so if you gave `mysqldump` instruction to dump all databases: `--all-databases`, only this user's database would be backed up and of course all general dbs he has access to. Usually it's `information_schema` only. It doesn't make dump size much bigger, in fact - no information from that schema is dumped - because it's dynamic info there. 
So by ensuring privileges for every user - you have simple solution to back up those users databases by just dumping "all databases".

Comment: Interesting. I had assumed mysqldump would error without rights to all DBs.  It looks like the dump using --all-databases is missing CREATE TABLE and USE directives which are useful on restore, but I imagine I can force it to include these with some additional switches?

Comment: Correction: --all-databases includes CREATE TABLE & USE directives.  Pass --no-create-db to omit CREATE TABLE.